# Jquery: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website cannot show the prices for different product options and I found the following error message on Chrome inspection:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

It is pointing to the line below:

```
  var first_variant_price = $('ul li input[type='radio']:checked').attr('data-price');
```

This is the complete script:

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var first_variant_price = $('ul li input[type='radio']:checked').attr('data-price'); 
  $('.current-price').text( first_variant_price );
  $('input[type='radio']').click(function() {
    var variant_price = $(this).attr('data-price');
    $('.current-price').text( variant_price);
  });
});
</script>
```

I could not realize any mismatch on this code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have problems with quotes. You may either escape `\'` the quotes around `radio` or simply change the code as follows:

```
// -.---------------------------------.
    v                                 v
  $("ul li input[type='radio']:checked").attr('data-price');
```

Comment: It worked! But I also had to change this: $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {

Comment: @user1749898 Yes, both selectors had the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you use quotes inside other quotes, either use a different type or escape them:

```
$("ul li input[type='radio']:checked") // different type of quotes
```

or

```
$('ul li input[type=\'radio\']:checked') // escape inner quotes via backslash
```

but the easiest way is to not quote the `radio` at all - it's not necessary.

```
$('ul li input[type=radio]:checked')
```